# Prevent self-developed software from being diagnosed as a virus

Tags: antivirus, virus

Let me describe my situation, I develop some accounting software of VB winform to use, normaly my software will modify registry to set offcie trusted location and whether the user who reads in registry has admin authority. However, I found here that it is no problem for VirusTotal to scan my exe on the first day after I developed the software. But after a few days, VirusTotal will appear and say that my exe is a virus,this makes my exe in the another computer antivirus detect as a virus, even if I run scaning on VirusTotal on the first day.

1. Why is it not a virus on the first day, but later diagnosed as a virus?
2. Is reading registry or modifying registry the cause of the diagnosed virus?
3. Any documentation or any behavior that is not allowed?
4. What can be done to avoid this problem other than to file a false positives list after it is detected as a virus

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus software works based on heuristics and signatures. In your case an actual virus may have similar behavior, e.g. because it modifies the same registry entries, which leads to the false positive. The is no "documentation on what is allowed" otherwise somebody writing an actual virus would use that as a rule book to evade detection. The delay in detection is likely caused because the antivirus software performs a periodic scan, which only then checks your executable.

Most antivirus software allows to mark files or directories as trusted and exclude them from scanning. This may be a suitable solution for you.